# Decidability of a Turing machine which always halts in at most ten steps

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability

I have an exam coming up soon and I need help with this.  Consider the problem:

> Given a Turing machine $M$, determine if $M$ halts in at most ten steps on every input.

Is this decidable?  Prove your answer.

Comment: What have you tried? Here is a hint: what can a machine do in 10 steps on input of size 12?

Comment: @Shaull if there should be an answer to this question (and there should), your comment should be it.  Can you make it into a short answer?

Comment: Dumping your exercise problem without any own effort is [bad style](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question).

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3101/is-the-set-of-turing-machines-which-stop-in-at-most-50-steps-on-all-inputs-deci

Answer (score 13):

Consider the following hint:

If $M$ is a TM, and it is given an input of length $12$ (for example), but you only allow $M$ to operate for $10$ steps, 
what can it do with the input?